# Применение ТФКП в Информационных технологиях?

Tags: математика, теория

Кто что знает, где может быть применен Теория Функции Комплексного Переменного в Информационных Технология, в т.ч. в Компьютерных наука (Криптография, Компьютерные зрение, Искусственный интеллект)... подскажите! Покидайте ссылки на статьи или книг. Мне задали написать реферат на эту тему, или не видать зачета и не допуск к экзамену по ТФКП :) Препод говорит что мол ТФКП актуально применяется в ИТ, бред полнейший в чем я убедился в поисках Google и Yandex.

Comment: Во всю применяется в пакетах для расчёта радио цепей, различных антенн, как именно в IT не знаю - никогда не встречал, да это там и не нужно. В остальных областях не знаю. Вам что именно интересно там? Вообще универовская ТФКП - это совсем немного, что можно этим словом назвать, так как есть целые классы уравнений, есть уравнения где не одна мнимая единица, а их например две, есть уравнения где дробные производные и т.д.  и всё это особо не вникая можно назвать "ТФКП".

Comment: Препод сказал напишешь реферат по этой теме, получишь зачет. Походу это мартышкин труд :) И именно в ИТ нужно! Спорил со мной что ТФКП мол активно применяется ИТ!!!

Comment: Переводить лень, так что я просто оставлю это здесь: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/15057/complex-analysis-in-theoretical-computer-science

Comment: О, короче, копайте в сторону аналитической комбинаторики. Это такое скрещивание теории производящих функций с ТФКП.

Видеокурс с ходу нагуглился тут: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LxuMs0EdUYw

Comment: Спасибо, еще и еще

Answer (score 1):

Первое и главное применение ТФКП - это возможность вычислять "неберущиеся" интегралы с помощью [теоремы о вычетах](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1736813/evaluate-the-following-definite-integral-int-infty-infty-fracx2-3x2/1736885#1736885).

Другая возможность - возможность решения и анализа тригонометрических уравнений
с помощью [формулы Муавра](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1823096/limit-of-the-solutions-of-a-trigonometric-equation/1829648#1829648) или замены тригонометрических функций комплексными экспонентами [для удобства дифференцирования](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1567441/how-to-evaluate-int-01-costx-over-sqrt1x2dx/1567944#1567944).

Заметим, что эти "математические выкрутасы" понемногу реализуются в современных офлайновых и [онлайновых](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Ci%5Cint_%7B-%5Cinfty%7D%5E%7B0%7D+%5Cfrac%7Bt%5E%7B2%7D%2B1%7D%7Bt%5E%7B4%7D%2B3t%5E%7B2%7D%2B1%7Ddt) пакетах и уже [поэтому](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gamma(x)%20integral%20representation&lk=3) имеют отношение к IT.